# Setting a NodeView to reflect the changes in the ListStore Model

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

Using `Mono`, `MonoDevelop`, `C#` and `GTK#` on Linux.

I know this has been asked before, but no matter what I try, none of the examples or answers seem to work for me. I still can't get the changes in my `ListStore` to be reflected in my `TreeView`.

I start of like so....

```
ListStore ls_nvDeviceFileDescription = new ListStore (typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string));
ListStore ls_dev_sensor_codes = new ListStore (typeof(string));
ListStore ls_dev_sensor_value_types = new ListStore (typeof(string));
```

The first `ListStore` is for the `TreeView`, the second and third is for my `CellRendererCombo`'s on Column 1 and 3 of my `TreeView`.

I add values to my `CellRendererCombo`'s for the user to pick values from....

```
string[] _codes = csql.CSQL_GetDeviceSensorCodes ();
string[] _types = csql.CSQL_GetDeviceSensorValueTypes ();

        // Do codes.
        if (_codes != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _codes.Length; i++) {
                ls_dev_sensor_codes.AppendValues (_codes [i]);
            }
        }

        //Do Types
        if (_types != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _types.Length; i++) {
                ls_dev_sensor_value_types.AppendValues (_types [i]);
            }
        }
```

I then bind my `ListStore` to they're appropriate two `CellRenderers`....

```
dev_sensor_codes.Model = ls_dev_sensor_codes;
dev_sensor_codes.TextColumn = 0;

dev_sensor_value_types.Model = ls_dev_sensor_value_types;
dev_sensor_value_types.TextColumn = 0;
```

And of course pack them onto they're respective Columns....

```
col_sensor_code.PackStart (dev_sensor_codes, true);
col_sensor_descr.PackStart (dev_sensor_descr, true);
col_sensor_value_type.PackStart (dev_sensor_value_types, true);
```

I then also bind my `ListStore` for the `TreeView` and append all my columns....

```
nvDeviceFileDescr.Model = ls_nvDeviceFileDescription;

nvDeviceFileDescr.AppendColumn (col_sensor_code);
nvDeviceFileDescr.AppendColumn (col_sensor_descr);
nvDeviceFileDescr.AppendColumn (col_sensor_value_type);
```

I also use the following code append a row to my `TreeView` (the only change that IS reflected).

```
ListStore store = (ListStore)nvDeviceFileDescr.Model;
TreeIter iter = store.Append ();
TreePath path = store.GetPath (iter);
nvDeviceFileDescr.SetCursor (path, nvDeviceFileDescr.Columns[0], true);
```

Now, I'll give two examples of Edited events that I'm sure should work, but doesn't....

Example 1:

```
dev_sensor_codes.Edited += delegate(object o, EditedArgs args) 
{
  ListStore store = (ListStore)nvDeviceFileDescr.Model;
  TreeSelection sel = nvDeviceFileDescr.Selection;
  TreeIter iter;

    if (!sel.GetSelected (out iter)) {
      return;
    }

    store.SetValue(iter, 1, args.NewText);
};
```

Example 2:

```
dev_sensor_value_types.Edited += delegate(object o, EditedArgs args) 
{
  ListStore store = (ListStore)nvDeviceFileDescr.Model;
  TreeIter iter;
  store.GetIterFromString(out iter, args.Path);
  store.SetValue (iter, 2, args.NewText);
};
```

In both examples I know I'm using a good `iter`, because `gtk` has good habit of letting you know if you have a stale iter (I think?), and the `TreePath`, must be good as it's passed through the Edited `args`.

I can verify that I get all the right iters, paths and values by printing to `stdout`, but I just can't get the changes in the `ListStore` for the `Treeview` reflected in the `TreeView`.

The only change that does show, is when I programatically `AppendValues`, or `Append`. It will add a new line in the `TreeView`, but no values ever show up.

Many, many thanks to anyone for a hand.

==========================================

## SOLUTION

So, as is SO often the case, we answer our own questions because we neglect to read our own code properly right?

I've left out a crucial step in the whole thing above and that is binding the CellRenderers to the actual columns. It 'looked' like I did, but I didn't, so here goes....

I packed the CellRenderers in the columns with the following....

```
Column.PackStart (CellRenderer, Bool);

//Or in my case
col_sensor_code.PackStart (dev_sensor_codes, true);
```

This is fine, but I also need to bind the CellRenderer to THAT column (or any other column actually)  SO......

```
Column.AddAttribute (CellRenderer, Attribute, Column Index);

// In my case that would be for instance....
col_sensor_code.AddAttribute (dev_sensor_codes, "text", 0);
```

So, many thanks for time and hope this helps some other blind fool ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not post the answer in the question.  Post the answer AS an answer, then [Accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Comment duly noted and please except my apology :)